# Article with revisions system

Tags: php, sql, database-design

For a project I am making I need the possibility (like stackoverflow does) to save all the previous edit (revisions) for posts.

Consider I can have some 1 to N association with the post (for example 1 post with 5 images associated).

How would you suggest me to design the database for this?
Of course the ID of the post should stay the same to don't broke URLs:

```
site/post/123 (whenever revisions it is)
```

Each revisions to posts should be manually approved so you can't show directly the last revisions inserted. How would you suggest me to design the db?

I have tought

```
Table: Post
postID | reviewID | isApproved | authorID |  text
```

And the image table (for example image, but it could be everything)

```
Secondary Table: Image
imageID | postID | reviewID | imagedata
```

Comment: Have you considered a version control system (for example, git, svn, etc.)?

Comment: @jdigital: I need my own solution

Comment: Can an image be associated with more than one post?

Comment: If you have some unique requirements that preclude using a version control system, can you tell us what they are?

Comment: This may be useful background consideration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485852/should-id-or-timestamp-be-used-to-determine-the-creation-order-of-rows-within-a given your requirement for revisions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I would split the post table in two, with the approved revisions in one, and the latest (not approved) revision in another. The rational is that any non approved revision which is not the latest would be supersceded by the next one (unless you really want to keep track of all the intermediate modifications, approved or not).

```
Table: OldPost
  postID | reviewID | authorID |  text

Table: PendingPost
  postID | authorID |  text
```

In that layout, whenever a new revision has been approved, it must be moved to the approved ones,  but you don't have to filter  them out when displaying the whole history, and conversely, you wont have to filter the approved revisions in the approval part of your site.

You could even refine the layout with yet another dedicated table for the latest approved revision (so three tables for the post in total, not counting attachements). This partitioning would improve the overall performance of your site for the most common queries, at the cost of more complex queries when you need all the data (less frequent operations).

```
Table: CurrentPost
   postID | authorID |  text
```

As you can see, this table structure is the same as the one for pending posts, so the updates would be trivial.
moving a revision to the old post table requires to find out the revision count, but you would have to do that operation anyway with a more classic db layout.

Regarding the attachment table, the layout seems to work.

Comment: same advise as the other answer, please add a database sample

Answer (score 1):

Separate all aspects of a post between global information and versionable information. In other words, what things can be changed in a revision and what are always going to apply to any revision. These are going to be the fields in your two tables, one for your posts, and one for the revisions. You will also need a row to specify what post the revision is for as well as whether the revision is approved, and on the posts table, you need a row to specify what the current revision in.

Comment: If you can, please add a sample of the database table